# recompiling raspbian for armv7, aarch64?

Tags: raspbian, arm

Do there exist straightforward ways of (re)compiling raspbian (any release) for armv6-related ISAs, like armv7/neon? Maybe binary blobs could be reused, even under aarch64? Can you give some pointers?

Answer (score 1):

**Debian "armhf" and "arm64" automatically started working when the new Raspberry Pi models were released (2015 and 2016)**, except for video acceleration and camera support.

Raspbian is itself  just a recompiled Debian targetting ARMv6 + VFPv2 instead of ARMv7. In 2012, no Raspberry Pi had an ARMv7 processor.

Debian "armel" has always worked on any Raspberry Pi and probably still does. Obviously the performance will be horrible.

Comment: I think there's an issue with proprietary binary blobs for the GPU, among other things. Also, I tried a debian aarch64 distro and it failed [miserably](https://github.com/Debian/raspi3-image-spec), kept resetting, drove all 4 cores to max temp.

Comment: AARCH64 is simply not stable and unsupported by the foundation. Especially the "VCHIQ" interface with the GPU firmware is 32bit only and not portable. The 32bit GPU itself and its firmware are wholly independent from the ARM and "just work".

Comment: Yeah, but ubuntu appears to support 64-bit as well as some other distros. Maybe someone will have more insight into this.